# Paypal response signature

Tags: php, paypal

I'm implementing PayPal Payments Advanced and I would like to ask how the response is secured from being changed on the way to my return url (eg: `http://my-site.com/eshopOrder/processPaymentResponse`). **Is there some signature of response (as used by many other payment methods)?** I cannot find any mention about this in developer [guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf).

It is not possible that the response come back unsecured. What will assure me that the response RESULT = 0 (means payment is ok) was not changed on the way?

Evidently, there is something I don't understand here :) Please, let me know what?

Thanks for help!

Mojo

Answer (score 0):

for secure case in paypal payment you can use your IPN verification

```
//all response post $_POST
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {         // Loop through the notification NV pairs
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));  // Encode the values
    $req .= "&$key=$value";                    // Add the NV pairs to the acknowledgement
  }
```

all the response data send to IPN  through the curl function and you can see how to IPN handle for paypal transaction.

```
  if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) { 
  //save you transaction success full
    // Response is VERIFIED
   }  else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
 // Response is INVALID
 }
```

i think it may help you for secure case.